# What is the best way to get a formatted string to represent UTC offset?

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting, timezone

I need to format a date like so: 20110202192008-0500.  The following code does the trick but I was wondering if there is a better/cleaner way to do this in c# 3.5.  Thanks!!

```
  var date = DateTime.Now;
  var strDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(date).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
  var offsetHours = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(date).Hours.ToString("00");
  var offsetMinutes = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(date).Minutes.ToString("00");
  Console.Write(string.Concat(strDate, offsetHours, offsetMinutes));
```

Comment: Just to make sure I've got this right: you're showing the UTC date and time, then offering the offset so the reader can do the math themselves? (Such that the example shows 14:20:08 local time.)

Comment: Excactly.  Just wondering if there is a cleaner way to get the string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this:

**.NET 4**

```
 var utcOffset = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
 Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ((utcOffset < TimeSpan.Zero) ? "-" : "+") + utcOffset.ToString("hhmm"));
```

**.NET 3.5**

```
 var utcAlmostFormat = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
 var utcFormat = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(utcAlmostFormat, @"(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)",@"$1$2");
 Console.WriteLine(utcFormat);
```

Go Steelers (from a guy in the Strip)

Comment: ToString on the TimeSpan doesn't have a format overload in 3.5 :(

Comment: @Mike - Ah damn, ok, yeah I would use  what you have or maybe use substring on the utcOffset.ToString() version.

Comment: @Mike - I added another version that should be ok on 3.5, just uses Regex to format the output.

Comment: The first example is wrong.  you have ToString("hhss").  It should be ToString("hhmm")

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `DateTimeOffset`, the custom specifier `zzz` will output the timezone offset, though in the more standard "+HH:mm" format. If you don't want the colon, a string replace will do the trick.

```
Debug.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmsszzz").Replace(":", ""));
// Result: "20110202153631-0500"
```

Comment: That wont produce the UTC time though.

Comment: The standard way to specify time and UTC offset is local time, and the offset from UTC. If you use UTC time, and a local offset that has not been applied to the time, then you're setting yourself up for errors, when someone assumes that it's done in the standard way.

Comment: I agree, just giving the OP what he wants :)

Comment: I am going to double check to make sure the format requirements are correct because that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some extension methods that will work in both .Net 3.5 and .Net 4.0 that will do exactly what you are asking in a very straight-forward way:

```
public static string ToStringWithOffset(this DateTime dt)
{
  return new DateTimeOffset(dt).ToStringWithOffset();
}

public static string ToStringWithOffset(this DateTime dt, TimeSpan offset)
{
  return new DateTimeOffset(dt, offset).ToStringWithOffset();
}

public static string ToStringWithOffset(this DateTimeOffset dt)
{
  string sign = dt.Offset < TimeSpan.Zero ? "-" : "+";
  int hours = Math.Abs(dt.Offset.Hours);
  int minutes = Math.Abs(dt.Offset.Minutes);

  return string.Format("{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}{1}{2:00}{3:00}", dt, sign, hours, minutes);
}
```

You can now call these on any DateTime or DateTimeOffset you wish.  For example:

```
string s = DateTime.Now.ToStringWithOffset();
```

or

```
string s = DateTimeTimeOffset.Now.ToStringWithOffset();
```

or

```
TimeSpan offset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(someDate);
string s = someArbitraryTime.ToStringWithOffset(offset);
```

or any other number of ways you can think of.

Answer (score 2):

We found that **DateTimeOffset.ToString("o")** is best for that. Example:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.UtcToDateTimeOffset(User.GetTimeZone()).ToString("o");
```

If you need to convert from DateTime, use helper method like:

```
    /// <summary>Converts from a UTC DateTime to the user's local DateTime</summary>
    /// <param name="utcDateTime">UTC DateTime</param>
    /// <param name="timeZoneInfo">The time zone info.</param>
    /// <returns>The DateTime in the user's time zone</returns>
    public static DateTimeOffset UtcToDateTimeOffset(this DateTime utcDateTime, TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = null)
    {
        if (utcDateTime.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc)
        {
            throw new InvalidTimeZoneException("Converting UTC to Local TimeZone, but was not UTC.");
        }

        DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(utcDateTime, TimeSpan.Zero);

        return timeZoneInfo.IsNotNull() ? dto.ToOffset(timeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(dto)) : dto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the `DateTime` [Standard Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) or create a [Custom Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

```
// Round-trip date/time pattern: "O", "o"
DateTime.Now.ToString("o") // "2018-01-15T11:00:50.5604578-05:00"
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o") // "2018-01-15T16:00:50.5604578Z"

// Universal sortable date/time pattern: "u"
DateTime.Now.ToString("u") // "2018-01-15 16:00:50.5604578Z"
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("u") // "2018-01-15 16:00:50.5604578Z"

// Custom format
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssK") // "20180115160050-05:00"
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssK") // "20180115160050Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```cs
var date = DateTimeOffset.Now;
var timestamp = $"{date:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff}{date.Offset.Ticks:+;-;}{date.Offset:hhmm}";
```

... or something like this.

Comment: should be {date.Offset:hh\\:mm}

Answer (score -1):

I think there are a lot of ways, for example:

```
  var offset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset;
  string result = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + offset.Hours.ToString("00") + offset.Minutes.ToString("00");
```

Comment: I dont think you want the `-` in there, as this implies the UTC Offset will always be negative.

Comment: -1: It is the offset of the current timezone, regardless of the daylight savings. Currently in Paris we're at UTC+2, but this code displays an offset of 1 hour